# Top level sass function for custom import

Tags: sass

I use SASS and now I need to import many partials from different places. For example, sometimes I must write something like this:

```
@import '../../../global/static/src/sass/example';
```

Is there some way to avoid duplicate all complicate way? I think about sass function, but as I see sass-funtions can not be call in top level of sass file. Is there any way to import file with adding prefix to it path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that due to the limitations of SASS compiler.

It is possible SASS variable only when your @import fits the following criteria:

> - It uses url().
> - It begins with "http://".
> - It ends with ".css".
> - It specifies a media query (e.g. @import "screen.css" screen).

[Source](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/49#issuecomment-3558440)